# iOS : pod update (unable to find the utility "xcode-select")

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6, cocoapods

xI am a new iOS developer.
Recently when I ran "pod update"
sth just went wrong

see the detail in the following:

---

***(unable to find the utility "xcode-select")***

```
bash-3.2$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
sh: line 1:  4936 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find xcode-select 2> /dev/null
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcode-select", not a developer tool or in PATH
Fetching podspec for `RBStoryboardLink` from `../RBStoryboardLink.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Using KIF (3.2.3)
Using RBStoryboardLink (0.1.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] The `UI Tests [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-UI Tests/Pods-UI Tests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `UI Tests [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-UI Tests/Pods-UI Tests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

#### but I already installed it

> bash-3.2$ xcode-select --install
>   xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

#### About my Xcode->preference->location

there is a command-line-tool 
And "Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a)" is selected (the only one can be selected)

Comment: Have you installed [xcode command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) ?

Comment: @tiper In your X-code preferences goto Locations and  select the command line tools, hope it helpful to you .Thanks

Comment: Thanks , I found that Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a) was already selected there(and it's the only one could be selected) @llesh

Comment: @Alladinian Yes , I already installed one , see detail information in my recently editing of the problem

Comment: you don't need to write `sudo` command every time.

Comment: @BadalShah If I don't use sudo , it seems that I can't use g++ etc